# How do Christian denominations interpret scriptures where Jesus said John is Elijah as anything other than indicating reincarnation?

Tags: exegesis, gospel-of-matthew, john-the-baptist, elijah, reincarnation

**Considering:**

Matthew 11:13-15 (King James Version):

> 13 For all the prophets and the law prophesied until John. 14 And if ye will receive it, this is Elias, which was for to come. 15 He that hath ears to hear, let him hear.

Matthew 17:12-13:

> 12 But I say unto you, That Elias is come already, and they knew him not, but have done unto him whatsoever they listed. Likewise shall also the Son of man suffer of them. 13 Then the disciples understood that he spake unto them of John the Baptist.

**The Question:** How do Christian denominations interpret scriptures where Jesus said John is Elijah as anything other than indicating reincarnation?

**Note** this is not a question about whether the Bible teaches reincarnation, nor whether the Bible says reincarnation is true, it is asking for how these verses are interpreted as anything other than reincarnation.  It's actually looking for the opposite of affirming reincarnation.

**Note:**

- Though in John 1 John the Baptist said he is not Elijah it is common, under theories of reincarnation, for someone to not know they are reincarnated.
- Though Elijah never died but was brought up to heaven, under theories of reincarnation a death is not required, only that a spirit once inhabiting a body inhabits another. Under some theories of reincarnation a spirit can inhabit multiple bodies simultaneously.
- The passage in the Bible that states "a man dies once and then face judgement" (Heb 9:27) is irrelevant to this question as those that use it to claim that the Bible teaches against reincarnation are misunderstanding what a man is and what reincarnation is.  A man is a combination of a Spirit, a Mind and a Body. A man dies once, the spirit may then be joined to another mind and body (i.e. reincarnated).  The second man is a different man who will also die once.
  Furthermore in answers to this question: [In what ways do Christian denominations reconcile the discrepancy between Hebrews 9:27 and its Biblical counter-examples?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/93215/60459) Heb 9:27 may not be stating a hard and fast rule.

Comment: There is a non-Buddhist notion of reincarnation in Judaism (see [*Gilgul*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gilgul) and [here](https://www.jewishvirtuallibrary.org/reincarnation-and-judaism) and [here](https://www.chabad.org/kabbalah/article_cdo/aid/380599/jewish/Judaism-and-Reincarnation.htm)).  But do these notions came *after* Jesus or *before* Jesus since Kaballah has a precursor in Merkabah mysticism.  If a notion of reincarnation *already* existed before Jesus, then the question becomes Jesus's judgment of this, since for Christians Jesus is the ultimate judge of oral Torah.

Comment: You can ask if reincarnation is a tenet of any Christian sect, but a question like this is nonsensical.  You can't simply get the answer you're looking for until you ask Jesus yourself.

Comment: @PeterTurner The question is closed since it's deemed to be asking for an opinion. I am new here and will learn how to ask questions

Comment: @scm that's great - just please take my advice.  There are a billion Christians and several thousand sects within Christianity, so if you ask "what does Jesus think" or "why does God..."  we don't want contradictory answers to questions.  Especially if they're both right according to different faith traditions.

Comment: since the thread has been closed I will venture this: Jesus saw John as the "second coming" of Elijah, but not as a reincarnation... rather in the sense that John was inspired by the "spirit and power" (Mal 4) of the prophet. This is a fairly standard answer to the question and personally I would like to see it re-opened.

Comment: This question seems to be pretty much a direct duplicate of an older question, now linked above.

Comment: @curiousdannii I did not ask if reincarnation is true, I asked how denominations interpret those scriptures as anything other than indicating reincarnation.

Comment: @scm And that's what the linked question covers

Answer (score 2):

No, and here's why? "Reincarnation, also known as rebirth or transmigration, is the philosophical or religious concept that the non-physical essence of a living being begins a new life in a different physical form or body after biological death"

Jesus Christ rose from the dead in the same body in which He died. This is confirmed at John 2:19-21. "Jesus answered them, "Destroy this temple, and in three days I will raise it up." Vs20, The Jews therefore said, "It took forth-six years to build this temple, and will You raise it up in three days?" Vs21, But He was speaking of the temple of His body."

You also have more proof that it was the same body at John 20:27, "The He said to Thoman, "Reach here your finger, and see My hands; and reach here your hand and put it into My side; and be not unbelieving, but believing."

How did Thomas react scm? John 20:28, "Thomas answered and said to Him literally, "The Lord of me and the God of me." Also at Hebrews 9:28, "so Christ also, having been offered once to bear the sins of many shall appear a second time for salvation/deliverance without reference to sin, to those who eagerly await Him."

This means that Jesus Christ came the first time and died for the sins of the world in order to bring man back to God by way of a personal relationship with Him. Jesus Christ is coming back a second time for His church in the same body He was crucified with and resurrected with. Also, notice verse 27 of Hebrews 9, "And inasmuch as it is appointed for men to die once and after this the judgment."

I know you mentioned this verse is "irrelevant" however, when combined with vs28 the definition of reincarnation is made void because the physical body of man is a transformation of the same bodies we had on earth just like Jesus Christ who is coming back in His same body. Please read Philippians 3:20-21.

Answer (score 0):

No, Jesus never mentions reincarnation, nor is this word used in the bible. Any potential correlation between teachings/happenings in the bible that could be stretched to fit reincarnation is just that a stretch

As Jesus doesn't explicitly mention reincarnation you have to rely on what he does say and what the rest of the Bible teaches.

From [this answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/25038/22319)

> ...we live once, die once, then are resurrected either to Heaven or Hell. Although there is the idea of a life different from the one we are living now, this eternal existence is quite different from the idea of living life again in the same or similar earthly context that is 'reincarnation'
>
> Hebrews 9:27 (ESV)
> 27  And just as **it is appointed for man to die once**, and after that comes judgment

This [answer](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/24197/whats-the-difference-between-resurrection-and-reincarnation) points out the differences between the two ideas, and resurrection is what is taught in bible and by Jesus

> Reincarnation involves living again, but having another life **in a new body, as a new person/being.**
>
> Resurrection involves living again **in your own body (or perhaps a glorified version of it), as yourself.**

See also [Isn't reincarnation affirmed by the Bible?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/11722/isnt-reincarnation-affirmed-by-the-bible) or [Is the biblical idea of being "born again" compatible with eastern religious ideas of reincarnation?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/3882/is-the-biblical-idea-of-being-born-again-compatible-with-eastern-religious-ide)

Comment: Hi. I'm looking for whether Jesus believed in reincarnation or not.  Trinity is also not explicitly mentioned, but a case could be made whether Jesus believed in that or not too.  The passage mentioned from the other answer is irrelevant. Even a reincarnated man dies once and then there is judgement.  Can you establish something like -- Jesus himself spoke against the concept

Comment: @scm the concept was foreign to Jews at the time (see other answers) and the word isn't used. You can't get references to something that isn't referenced. The trinity is a different subject completely

Comment: I've added some explanation in my question as to why "a man dies once" is irrelavent

Comment: @scm see difference between reincarnation and resurrection. Please read any of the four answers I reference.